# how to change the @FeignClient name in runtime

Tags: spring, spring-cloud

I use Spring Cloud Netflix to build my micro service .

```
@FeignClient(name = "ms-cloud",configuration = MsCloudClientConfig.class)      
public interface TestClient {                                                  

/**                                                                        
 * @return                                                                 
 */                                                                        
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)               
String test();                                                             

}
```

I want to change the name to ms-cloud-pre when some special user.
Anyone can give some advice?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-cloud-netflix.adoc#overriding-feign-defaults) feign supports placeholders in the `name` and `url` fields.

```
@FeignClient(name = "${store.name}")
public interface StoreClient {
    //..
}
```

So you could set `store.name=storeProd` at runtime using normal spring boot configuration mechanisms.

Comment: Note: you can't change it dynamically based on a parameter or local context.

Comment: As a normal user , store.name=storeProd ,but with some credential , store.name=storeProd-pre ,.

Comment: No, you can't do that.

Answer (score 2):

To create a spring-cloud Feign client at runtime in situations where you don't know the service-id until the point of call:

```
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientBuilder;

@Component
public class InfoFeignClient {

  interface InfoCallSpec {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/actuator/info", method = GET)
    String info();
  }

  FeignClientBuilder feignClientBuilder;

  public InfoFeignClient(@Autowired ApplicationContext appContext) {
    this.feignClientBuilder = new FeignClientBuilder(appContext);
  }

  public String getInfo(String serviceId) {

    InfoCallSpec spec =
        this.feignClientBuilder.forType(InfoCallSpec.class, serviceId).build();

    return spec.info();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That actually is possible. In Spring Cloud Zookeeper we're doing a similar thing since the name of the service in the Feign client is not the one that is there in the in Zookeeper. It can be an alias presented in the yaml file. Here you have the code example https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-zookeeper/blob/master/spring-cloud-zookeeper-discovery/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/zookeeper/discovery/dependency/DependencyRibbonAutoConfiguration.java#L54 and here you have the description of the dependencies feature - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-zookeeper/blob/master/docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-cloud-zookeeper.adoc#using-the-zookeeper-dependencies

Comment: Maybe it's a graceful way to implement

Comment: Is it  a questino or statement? :P I mean does it help you in anyway?

Comment: Now i use eureka as register server center

Comment: So you can use the same approach as the one I've shown you. There's nothing there out of the box. You'd have to build it on your own.