# JHipster AuthorizedFeignClient Dynamic Name

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, jhipster, spring-cloud-feign

I'm looking for a way to use dynamic names with the @AuthorizedFeignClient annotation. I have multiple instances of the same microservices - each having a different name, and I need a way to specify which one to contact.

This is my Microservice client:

```
@AuthorizedFeignClient(name = "some changing name")
public interface MyClient {
    @RequestMapping(path = "/api/resource", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    String getResoruce();
}
```

And I need a way to specify which instance to contact

```
@Autowired
protected MyClient myClient;

// somehow need to specify which microservice to call
// based on the name passed in
foo(String name) {
    myClient.getResources()
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible based on this comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35168148/how-to-change-the-feignclient-name-in-runtime#comment58094066_35188454 but I don't know for sure

Comment: Could you describe why you need to do so? This seems to goes against microservices architecture principles. If you must do so anyway, you could either build a REST client manually (without using annotations) or go through a gateway and implements your routing strategy there if it relies on some metadata.

Comment: Each user is going to have their own computing environment with a local microservice deployed.